# inputMask when save null set zero

Tags: spring, jsf

Has one form **client.xhtml**, in form has a field

```
<p:inputMask mask="9999" id="idYear" value="#{bean.year}" label="#{msg['year']}" />
```

- Primefaces 6.1
- Spring 4.2
- Jsf 2.1

**When click**

```
<p:commandButton id="btnSave" value="#{msg['curric.save']}"
                                process="form"
                                action="#{controller.save}"
                                update="form" />
```

When it arrives in the backBean the value of the year is zero, but I did not information anything...

- Where is this zero coming from?
- How can I solve this?

Comment: Try `process="@form"`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25339056/understanding-primefaces-process-update-and-jsf-fajax-execute-render-attributes

Comment: i'm try, but not work

Comment: Are you implying that is does work for a regular `p:inputText`?